# Is an ArrayList or a LinkedList better for sorting?

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I want to use data structure that needs to be sorted every now and again. The size of the data structure will hardly exceed 1000 items.

Which one is better - `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`?

Which sorting algorithm is better to use?

Comment: What is your hypothesis?  What did you learn when you tested your hypothesis?

Comment: Take a look at this and i am sure you will come up with a conclusion for yourself.
Regards! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist

Comment: at the size you are considering, either will be the same, I 100% this will **not** be a bottle neck in your application. Always profile yourself and see what you find with your data, only you can do that!

Comment: Wouldn't a heap be best?

Comment: Note: Poster notes in a comment below that maximum list size may grow in the future beyond 1000 items.

Comment: Related - [When to use LinkedList<> over ArrayList<>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)

Comment: I like how none of the answers actually answer the question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Up to Java 7, it made no difference because `Collections.sort` would dump the content of the list into an array.

With Java 8, using an `ArrayList` should be slightly faster because `Collections.sort` will call `List.sort` and `ArrayList` has a specialised version that sorts the backing array directly, saving a copy.

So bottom line is `ArrayList` is better as it gives a similar or better performance depending on the version of Java.

Answer (score 9):

If you're going to be using `java.util.Collections.sort(List)` then it really doesn't matter.

<del>If the `List` does not implement `RandomAccess`, then it will be dumped to a `List`</del> The list will get dumped into an array for purposes of sorting anyway.

(Thanks for keeping me honest Ralph. Looks like I confused the implementations of sort and shuffle. They're close enough to the same thing right?)

Comment: This is not what the java doc say or the implementation does (or at least how I understand them):  JavaDoc "This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element"  -- It dumps into an Array (not a List) and this is done, no matter if it implements RandomAccess or not.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use the Apache library, then have a look at [TreeList](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/TreeList.html). It addresses your problem correctly.

Comment: Or simply the standard TreeSet, with no additional dependencies.

Comment: TreeSet does not give access using index

Answer (score 3):

Only 1000 items? Why do you care?

I usually always use ArrayList unless I have specific need to do otherwise.

Have a look at the source code. I think sorting is based on arrays anyway, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I care because it is not the final size. It may increase with time

Answer (score 1):

If you are just sorting and not dynamically updating your sorted list, then either is fine and an array will be more memory efficient. Linked lists are really better if you want to maintain a sorted list. Inserting an object is fast into the middle of a linked list, but slow into an array.

Arrays are better if you want to find an object in the middle. With an array, you can do a binary sort and find if a member is in the list in O(logN) time. With a linked list, you need to walk the entire list which is very slow.

I guess which is better for your application depends on what you want to do with the list after it is sorted.

Comment: *Inserting an object is fast into the middle of a linked list, but slow into an array.*  However, finding the location to insert into takes `O(n)` time in a linked list vs `O(log n)` in an ArrayList.  The complexity is a wash.  In actual fact the only reason sorting a linked list in Java (i.e. `Collections.sort()`) is acceptably fast is because it dumps the entire list into an array list and sorts that, then dumps it back to a linked list.

Comment: The complexity is a wash and the local access in memory is significantly (experiments I saw and tested were around 40%) faster for large data sets.